# How to pass HTML style classes into a Javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way that I can pass all style classes into a function?

The style classes represent a table row and i'm trying to hide all rows with the exception of the one that is being clicked. (code below, I apologise if it isn't in the code tags)

```
function toggle_visibility(id, param2, param3)
{
    var getClasses = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    var getClasses2 = document.getElementsByClassName(param2);
    var getClasses3 = document.getElementsByClassName(param3);

    for (var i = 0; i < getClasses.length; i++) 
    {
        if(getClasses[i].style.display == 'none')
        {
            getClasses[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

     for (var i = 0; i < getClasses2.length; i++) 
     {
        if(getClasses2[i].style.display == '')
        {
            getClasses2[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < getClasses3.length; i++) 
     {
        if(getClasses3[i].style.display == '')
        {
            getClasses3[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
     }
}
```

The code works but isn't scalable currently so I would like to pass in every class and then search the classes with an 'if' statement. is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arguments variable :

```
function toggle_visibility()
{
    var first = true;
    var i,j, getClasses;

    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        getClasses = document.getElementsByClassName(arguments[i]);

        for (j = 0; j < getClasses.length; j++) 
        {
            if(getClasses[j].style.display == (first ? 'none' : ''))
            {
                getClasses[j].style.display = (first ? '' : 'none');
            }
        }
        first = false;
    }
}
```

With this you can call your function with any number of arguments, the first will be shown and all the other hidden

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of all the classes available in the DOM and pass it as an argument to the function.

```
var All= document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var allClasses=[];
for(var i=0; i< All.length;i++){
  if(All[i].className){
    allClasses.push(All[i].className);
  }
}

function toggle_visibility(allClasses)
{
   //do whatever you want!
}
```

Comment: Isn't calling document.getElementsByTagName("*") a bit brutal for the browser and the memory ?

Comment: yeah! but this is one way of doing it, not the best though!